# Show discount including tax, calculate discount excluding tax

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, tax, discount, coupon

I want to display the discount amount including tax on cart overview page (totals summary).

- Magento 2.1.8

Relevant settings:

- Catalog prices: Excluding tax
- Apply Customer Tax: After discount
- Apply Discount On Prices: Excluding tax

Current situation in total summary within cart:
[image: totals summary]

I cannot set `Apply Discount On Prices` to `Including Tax`, because Magento then calculates wrong totals. So in short I need to calculate discount amounts excluding tax but displaying including tax.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the *warning* message in the Magento Back office in Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Calculation Settings -> Apply Discount On Prices:

> To apply the discount on prices including tax and apply the tax after
>   discount, set Catalog Prices to “Including Tax”.

To do what you want, you need to customize the Magento Tax module

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement observer for this. Maybe it help to someone.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after">
        <observer name="vendor_module_fix_total_discount_amount" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\FixTotalDiscountAmount" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and its implementation

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total;
use Magento\Tax\Model\Config as TaxConfig;

class FixTotalDiscountAmount implements ObserverInterface
{
    private TaxConfig $taxConfig;

    private PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency;

    public function __construct(TaxConfig $taxConfig, PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency)
    {
        $this->taxConfig = $taxConfig;
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Quote $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getData('quote');

        /** @var Total $total */
        $total = $observer->getData('total');

        if (!$this->taxConfig->displayCartPricesInclTax()) {
            // Don't need to add tax into discount.
            return;
        }
    
        if (
            $this->taxConfig->applyTaxAfterDiscount() // Apply Tax After Discount
            && !$this->taxConfig->discountTax() // Apply Discount on Prices Excluding Tax
            && !$this->taxConfig->priceIncludesTax() // Catalog Prices Excluding Tax
        ) {
            // Add "missing" Discount Tax from all Items
            foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                $discountTax = $item->getRowTotalInclTax() - $item->getRowTotal() - $item->getTaxAmount();
                $baseDiscountTax = $item->getBaseRowTotalInclTax() - $item->getBaseRowTotal() - $item->getBaseTaxAmount();

                $discountAmount = $total->getDiscountAmount() - $discountTax; // minus because discounts are negative numbers
                $baseDiscountAmount = $total->getBaseDiscountAmount() - $baseDiscountTax;

                $total->setDiscountAmount($this->priceCurrency->roundPrice($discountAmount));
                $total->setBaseDiscountAmount($this->priceCurrency->roundPrice($baseDiscountAmount));
            }
        }
    }
}
```